# Update field with Regular Expression (or similar)

Tags: sql-server, regex, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So there's a field in my table called Url wich looks like this:
`/MyServer/MyPage?Param=XXX`.
I need to run a script in order to update that field from `XXX` to say `YYY`. I do have the rules on what `YYY` corresponds to what `XXX`, the thing is that I don't know how to update ONLY the fields whose param is exaclty `Param` and no other.

So these would be the updates:

```
/MyServer/MyPage?Param=XXX        ==>  /MyServer/MyPage?Param=XXX  
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAA   ==>  /MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=BBB
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=JJJ  ==>  /MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=JJJ 
                                       (last row no changes since it is not param)
```

Have I made myself clear?

**Edit:** I have a aux table with the correpsondation `XXX` `YYY`. Keep in mind `XXX` is just an example. Actually the parameter is an integer so the length of the param value is variable

Comment: Did the first line mean to have YYY at the end of the "after" value? Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using sql server 2008, and yes, the string to replace is always at the end

Answer (score 2):

This takes care of Mikael's concern, that the `AAA`, `XXX` etc. could appear in the URL. It also deals with the case where the parameter is not the last one in the URL.

```
DECLARE @URLs TABLE (URL VARCHAR(2000));

INSERT @URLs SELECT '/MyServer/MyPage?Param=XXX'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAA'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServerAAA/MyOtherPage?Param=AAA'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=JJJ'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAA&Param2=JJJ'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=AAA&Param=AAA';

DECLARE @rules TABLE(pSrc VARCHAR(32), pDest VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @rules SELECT 'XXX', 'YYY'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'AAA', 'BBB'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'JJJ', 'KKK';

;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT URL, 
    pre = LEFT(URL, CHARINDEX('?', URL)-1), 
    post =  SUBSTRING(URL, CHARINDEX('?', URL), 2000)
  FROM @URLs
), sub AS
(
    SELECT src.URL, src.pre, src.post, r.pSrc, r.pDest, 
      i = PATINDEX('%[?&]Param=' + r.pSrc + '&%', post + '&')
    FROM src INNER JOIN @Rules AS r
    ON src.post + '&' LIKE '%[?&]Param=' + r.pSrc + '&%'
)
UPDATE u SET URL = pre + STUFF(post, i+7, LEN(pSrc), pDest)
FROM @URLs AS u INNER JOIN sub ON u.URL = sub.URL;

SELECT * FROM @URLs;
```

Results:

```
URL
--------------------------------
/MyServer/MyPage?Param=YYY
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=BBB
/MyServerAAA/MyOtherPage?Param=BBB
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=JJJ
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=BBB&Param2=JJJ
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=AAA&Param=BBB
```

Adding doc links for follow-up question. Yes, `STUFF` is a function.

[STUFF (Transact-SQL) : MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)
[PATINDEX (Transact-SQL) : MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)

Comment: This could get you into trouble if the parameter also is a part of the URL. `/MyAAAServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAA` becomes `/MyBBBServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAA`.

Comment: Thanks @Mikael, I think I've addressed that.

Comment: Uh, yup, thanks again. I swapped between individual and union obviously.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I think you'll get more flexibility if you move the hardcoded `param=` from the `sub` to `@rules`, and replace `i+7` with `i+1`. This way `@rules` can mix in other parameters, e.g. `param2=CCCC` => `param2=MM`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table
(
  Col varchar(50)
)

insert into @T values
('/MyServer/MyPage?Param=XXX'),
('/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAA'),
('/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=JJJ')

declare @P table
(
  ID int,
  P1 varchar(50),
  P2 varchar(50)
)

insert into @P values
(1, 'AAA', 'BBB'),
(2, 'XXX', 'YYY')

update T 
set Col = left(T.Col, len(T.Col)-len(P.P1))+P.P2
from @T as T
  inner join @P as P
    on right(T.Col, len(P.P1)+6) = 'Param='+P.P1
where P.ID = 1

select *
from @T
```

Result:

```
Col
--------------------------------------------------
/MyServer/MyPage?Param=XXX
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=BBB
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=JJJ
```

Comment: +1 uncanny timing. I used `STUFF` because I think it will be easier to adapt if the parameter isn't actually at the end of the string.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yes, STUFF is nice. I think you should do some calculation using REVERSE in your answer to find the last occurrence the the string.

Comment: I went a slightly different route with the same end result.

Comment: If Param2=AAA, this will incorrectly change it to Param2=BBB. Also Param=AAAA becomes Param=ABBB.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - Almost there, but missed `Param=XXX`. I think removing `where P.ID = 1` will fix that.

Comment: @JohnDewey - Yes. Took it from OP*s "Actually the parameter is an integer" and assumed that he meant that the parameter specifies what row in the AUX table he wants to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `replace()` method.

EDIT: Added flexibility.

```
declare @myURLs table(url varchar(1000))
insert into @myURLs values ('/MyServer/MyPage?Param=XXX&Param2=JJJ'); --should update
insert into @myURLs values ('/MyServer/MyPage?Param2=XXX'); --should not update
insert into @myURLs values ('/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=JJJ&Param=AAA'); --should update
insert into @myURLs values ('/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAAA'); --should not update
insert into @myURLs values ('/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAAA&Param2=JJJ'); --should not update

declare @replacements table(targetStr varchar(80), replStr varchar(80));
insert into @replacements values ('Param=AAA','Param=BBB');
insert into @replacements values ('Param=XXX','Param=YYY');

-- ANSI-92 syntax
update u
set url=REPLACE(url,r.targetStr,r.replStr)
from @myURLs u
inner join @replacements r on 
    (PATINDEX('%[?&]'+r.targetStr,url)>0
    or PATINDEX('%[?&]'+r.targetStr+'[?&]%',url) > 0);  

SELECT * 
FROM @myURLs;
```

Result:

```
url
------------------------------------------------
/MyServer/MyPage?Param=YYY&Param2=JJJ
/MyServer/MyPage?Param2=XXX
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=JJJ&Param=BBB
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAAA
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=AAAA&Param2=JJJ
```

Comment: Why would you join on 1=1 and then add the join criteria in the where clause? I understand that it's legal and works, but it's an extra clause for no obvious purpose. I'd ask about the purpose of the identity column on the replacements table but I'm much more curious about the join. Also why the while loop? Shouldn't your update affect the whole set in one shot?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Thanks for point these out. The `WHILE` and `id` were baggage left over from a previous iteration, and now obsolete. The simpler query is updated.

Comment: Oh, the horror! Non-ANSI joins? I preferred the ON 1=1 to be quite honest. :-/

Comment: @AaronBertrand - It's logically equivalent to 1=1, but the old ANSI-86 standard, I think.

Comment: Butt why not inner join on pat index? The old style is not good practice to perpetuate and encourage, IMHO, because it's too easy to accidentally go Cartesian and it also makes it a pain to change to outer joins (since * =/= *are deprecated).

Comment: @sebastian It's a feature not a bug. 4 and 5 don't get updated because AAAA is not AAA, as specified in the rule table. If you update the rule table to AAAA, then the replacements will occur in 4 & 5. I'm basically attempting an exact word match to avoid unintended side effects.

Comment: I don't want to update depending on the value of the param... I need to update the value depending of the name of the param... if I have Param2=AAA I don't want to update, if I have Param=AAAAAAAAAAAAA I DO want to update

Comment: Then you would populate the @replacements table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it, and because the original question did mention RegEx, I thought I would give an example that uses Regular Expressions. Yes, this does require SQLCLR and not everyone can or will use that, but it is an option.

This example does use an existing SQLCLR library called [SQL# (SQLsharp)](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=so_9561340) of which I am the author, but the Regular Expression functions (with only 3 exceptions) are free.

The example uses the sample URLs and Rules table variables from Aaron Bertrand's answer, but changes the "source" strings to be numbers (as that is the original request and the Regular Expression is specific in that regards) and I added a test-case to show that a string of "222" does not match any part of "2222".

```
DECLARE @URLs TABLE (URL VARCHAR(2000));

INSERT @URLs SELECT '/MyServer/MyPage?Param=111'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=222'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer222/MyOtherPage?Param=222'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer222/MyOtherPage?Param=2222'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=333'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=222&Param2=333'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=2222&Param2=333'
   UNION ALL SELECT '/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=222&Param=222';

DECLARE @Rules TABLE(pSrc VARCHAR(32), pDest VARCHAR(32));

INSERT @Rules SELECT '111', 'YYY'
    UNION ALL SELECT '222', 'BBB'
    UNION ALL SELECT '2222', 'bbb'
    UNION ALL SELECT '333', 'KKK';


SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace(u.url,
            '(.*Param=)' + r.pSrc + '([^0-9]+|$)',
            '$1' + r.pDest + '$2',
            -1, 1, '')
FROM @URLs u
CROSS JOIN @Rules r
WHERE SQL#.RegEx_IsMatch(u.url,
            '(.*Param=)' + r.pSrc + '([^0-9]+|$)',
            1, '') = 1

-- OR, using RegEx look-behind and look-ahead
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace(u.url,
            '(?<=Param=)' + r.pSrc + '(?=[^0-9]+|$)',
            r.pDest,
            -1, 1, '')
FROM @URLs u
CROSS JOIN @Rules r
WHERE SQL#.RegEx_IsMatch(u.url,
            '(?<=Param=)' + r.pSrc + '(?=[^0-9]+|$)',
            1, '') = 1
```

Results:

```
/MyServer/MyPage?Param=YYY
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=BBB
/MyServer222/MyOtherPage?Param=BBB
/MyServer222/MyOtherPage?Param=bbb
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=BBB&Param2=333
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param=bbb&Param2=333
/MyServer/MyOtherPage?Param2=222&Param=BBB
```

To be fair to the strict T-SQL solutions, this was not tested for performance but for functionality and flexibility. Which solution performs better would have to be tested on your server.